# display printed out text as if it was written by an human (C)

Tags: c, printf

What I'm trying to do idk if it's possible, but since my teacher said he would raise my calification I'll give it a try...

I got an array of chars

```
char myArray[100]
```

the thing to do it's to printf all the array it step by step, like a human being was writing it, a character, delay, another, delay, etc

how should I do it?

print `myArray[i]` in a loop and do something? I could think of doing a loop that runs a lotta times before it breaks, but its not like an elegant solution...

thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Windows then use `sleep` function. If you are on Linux, then use `usleep` function.

Comment: never heard about that function, its all SO's compatible? ill do some research

Answer (score 0):

Hand this over to your teacher for top marks. Be warned: you might be asked to explain it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

void my_delay (int millisec)
{
    clock_t start = clock(), end = start + (millisec*CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    while (clock() < end) ;
}

void stutter_write (char *string)
{
    int i, typos;

    while (*string)
    {
        // random delay
        my_delay (1+(rand() & 255));

        // randomly inject typos
        typos = 1+(rand() % 20);
        if (typos < 4)
        {
            for (i=0; i<typos; i++)
            {
                // wrong digit
                if (isdigit(*string))
                    putchar ((rand() % 10)+'0');
                else
                // random letter
                    putchar ((rand() % 26)+'a'+32*(rand() & 31 < 10));
                fflush (stdout);
                // wait for it ..
                my_delay (200+(rand() & 511));
            }
            // oh blast. backspace:
            while (typos--)
            {
                putchar (8);
                fflush (stdout);
                my_delay (100+(rand() & 127));
            }
        }
        // space, lowercase or number: fast
        if (*string == ' ' || islower(*string) || isdigit(*string))
        {
            my_delay (250);
        } else
        // uppercase: slightly slower
        if (isupper(*string))
        {
            my_delay (350);
        } else
        // some common symbols on keyboard: unshifted
        if (strchr("[]=-';.,/", *string))
        {
            my_delay (400);
        } else
        // all others are shifted and/or hard to find or something like that
            my_delay (600);
        putchar (*string);
        fflush (stdout);
        string++;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i,j;

    srand(0);   
    for (i=1; i<argc; i++)
    {
        if (i > 1) stutter_write (" ");
        stutter_write (argv[i]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Usage: (assuming the name of your program is "stutter"

```
stutter Here is a long string, which will be output as typed by a human. No, really.
```

.. and the string will appear in your console as if typed by a hunt-and-pick typist (adjust delay rates to simulate more advanced typists).

Mimicking more "natural" typos is way harder. Common typos (making it up while I write) are: typing a few words, thinking it over, backspacing all and type something else; transposition ("instaed" instead of "instead"), forgetting Shift ("0" instead of "("), wrong row of keyboard ("wbat" instead of "what"), shift one character up on keyboard ("ehat" instead of "what"), forgetting a character ("wat" instead of "what").